# How to update and return a query based on dynamic results of a second?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**PROBLEM**
I have a query that selects groups of items based on their ID and returns a count.

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| ID | description | count | location |  
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| 10 | apples      | 20    | NULL     |
| 11 | oranges     | 15    | NULL     |
| 12 | pears       | 10    | NULL     |
| 13 | grapes      | 10    | NULL     |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
```

I have a second query that selects the same group of items that have been assigned to a location. In this example, all 20 `apples` are assigned to `desk`, and all but one of the `oranges` have been assigned: 9 to the `fridge` and 5 to the `desk`, leaving 1 without a location.

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| ID | description | count | location |  
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| 10 | apples      | 20    | desk     |
| 11 | oranges     | 9     | fridge   |
| 11 | oranges     | 5     | desk     | - 1 orange is still unassigned
| 12 | pears       | 8     | drawer   |
| 12 | pears       | 2     | shelf    |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
```

In SQL, is there a way to combine the above two queries to produce the result shown below?

**WHAT I WANT**

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| ID | description | count | location |  
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
| 10 | apples      | 20    | desk     | - 1 to 1 match
| 11 | oranges     | 9     | fridge   | - 9/15 in fridge
| 11 | oranges     | 5     | desk     | - 5/15 in desk
| 11 | oranges     | 1     | NULL     | - 1/15 unassigned (NULL)
| 12 | pears       | 8     | drawer   | - 8/10 in drawer
| 12 | pears       | 2     | shelf    | - 2/10 in shelf (all assigned)
| 13 | grapes      | 10    | NULL     | - no grapes assigned, location (NULL)
+----+-------------+-------+----------+
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
`UNION` - combines the two queries into one, but doesn't do any math or logic
`JOIN` - I've tried joining the two queries with derived tables, but again can't figure out the logic

Comment: I'll guess yyour schema, but it would be better if you included it.  Also, *must* we re-use the code you wrote for the first two?  (Are they views for example?)  Or can we re-write from scratch?  [I'll do the latter]

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to merge two views into one. I understand your method but, using "apples" as an example, wouldn't the resultant query list the 20 apples twice? Once in "desk" and once in NULL?

Comment: @Paul - Why on earth would they?  Although `null` doesn't really compare to anything, it most definitely isn't considered _something else_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 gets you a listing of the total numbers of fruits, grouped by fruit type.

Query 2 gets you a listing of the total numbers of fruits at each location, but excludes ones that are not at any recorded location.

If you sum the results from query 2 and group them by fruit type, that gives you a total number of fruits that are at -any- recorded location. In the case of the oranges in your table, this total would be 14, leaving one at a NULL location.

What might work as a solution is a combination of UNION and subquery, getting the specific results for each location (as per query 2), and then UNIONing them with a subquery that returns the total amounts of fruit existing minus the total amount of fruit existing in a known location:

```
/* Setup sample view outputs */

declare @query_1 table (id int, description varchar(50), total int, location varchar(50))
declare @query_2 table (id int, description varchar(50), total int, location varchar(50))

insert into @query_1
SELECT 10  , 'apples' , 20  , NULL 
UNION SELECT 11 , 'oranges'     , 15     , NULL   
UNION SELECT 12 , 'pears'       , 10    , Null   
UNION SELECT 13 , 'grapes'       , 10     , Null

insert into @query_2
SELECT       10 ,  'apples'     , 20    , 'desk'    
UNION SELECT 11 , 'oranges'     , 9     , 'fridge'   
UNION SELECT 11 , 'oranges'     , 5     , 'desk'     
UNION SELECT 12 , 'pears'       , 8     , 'drawer'   
UNION SELECT 12 , 'pears'       , 2     , 'shelf'    


/* Get Query 2 first to find all fruits that are at specific locations */

select * from @query_2

UNION

/* Then take subquery: For each fruit ID in query 1, find the total amount of fruit with that ID that exists in a specified location (as per query 2)
   Subtract that amount from query 2 from query 1, and return any nonzero results to be UNIONed. */

select q1.id, q1.description, total - ISNULL(fruit_in_loc,0) as total, q1.location from @query_1 q1
    outer apply 
    (
        select id, SUM(total) as fruit_in_loc 
        from @query_2 q2
        where q1.id = q2.id 
        group by id


    ) q2_subtotal
    where (fruit_in_loc <> total) or fruit_in_loc is null

order by id, total desc
```

This is definitely a little clunky, and you would likely be better served by having a view or query to specifically get this result set out rather than interweaving two different views like this. If you don't have deeper access within the database than these two views, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  fruit.id           AS [ID],
  fruit.name         AS [description],
  COUNT(*)           AS [count]
  location.name      AS [location]
FROM
  fruit
LEFT JOIN
  fruit_item
    ON fruit_item.fruit_id = fruit.id
LEFT JOIN
  location
    ON location.id = fruit_item.location_id
GROUP BY
  fruit.id,
  fruit.name,
  location.name
ORDER BY
  fruit.id,
  fruit.name,
  location.name
```

Comment: @AndriyM - I'm still getting used to these new powers.  Great responsibility and all...